# Is Lelouch's Geass limited in what it can tell people to do?

Tags: code-geass

Yes, I know that Lelouch can only use his Geass once per person, but can he control everything? I mean, if he says "I command you to do whatever I say", will it work?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it would, and he have done so on multiple occasions.

> (For instance, on Schneizel, "Obey zero")

Comment: And this works forever?

Comment: There is no known time limit.

Comment: Yeah, he can order you to die, or follow his or anyone's commands for ever. He just chose not to at the beginning of the series.

Comment: There are limits mostly physical (breathe underwater forever), you just don't see it since he does extensive testing when he first acquires it to test possible limits.  It's also shown multiple times people can resist it to some extent if it goes against their core beliefs. But he can issue all encompassing slave command that's active forever unless geass canceled.

Comment: The "Obey/Serve Zero" command is a good example however Schneizel and the Damocles Guards obeys Zero which is whoever is identified as Zero (so it's actually meant to have them obey Suzaku in accordance to Lelouch's plan). a better example relating to the question of Lelouch himself telling people to obey him are the soliders is in the Imperial Court in episode 22. his command is "Be my slaves... NOW!"

Answer (score 1):

Lelouch has done so several times. One of it is like Madara said. Here's another examples:

1. To Kururugi Suzaku, "Live!"
2. To Gilford, "Whenever you see Zero putting his hand on his collar, you will see him as Princess Cornelia."

The limitations is of course the physical limitations of the subject of the Geass power. For example if he ordered someone to go to the Moon on foot, then it will not happen.

Comment: So that means, that if i would command to someone, to live, then he wouldn't be able to die?

Comment: I think not. Just that he will do his best to survive. Like in Suzaku's case, when he was about to be sacrificed to kill Zero, he suddenly goes against his order and let Zero move from the bombing point.

Comment: Specifically, Lelouch gives the order "Live!" to [a particular girl] after she's been shot, as he's trying desperately to stop her dying. She's wounded too badly for an effort of will to save her, though, so she still dies.